# Show images on a monitor using Arduino via Wifi

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, display

Consider a computer monitor hanging on a wall. Next to it is an Arduino Uno with a wifi. Is it possible to create something like this? Using wifi it should be possible to send data (images) to Arduino. This will be output to a monitor, like an image gallery. Images can be any type (videos included).

Is it possible? Where does one start?

Thank you.

Comment: This should be a fun challenge, if you're looking for a learning experience. As others have pointed out, you'll be working at the limits of the Arduino to get much of anything to work. If your goal is results, on the other hand, you'd be best off rethinking your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have somewhere in my stash a shield that enables an Arduino to overlay graphics on the screen. But it is kinda crude and low-res. What you're trying to achieve is definitely not for Arduino, it is way underpowered.

You'd better look into doing this with something like a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [GameDuino shield](http://excamera.com/sphinx/gameduino/) which gives you a full VGA experience on your Arduino. Also good for making games with.

Answer (score 1):

For the novice/intermediate, this is going to take way too much time and effort to meet the requirements you have asked with an Arduino Uno (if it is even possible).

May I suggest a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) instead.

The Raspberry Pi ([depending on the model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications)) has multiple video outputs:

- HDMI
- Composite video
- LCD display

Each of these video outputs require very little effort to get going.

Adding WiFi capability requires just a USB WiFi dongle (and possibly downloading a driver) a bit of set-up and that about it. The RPi 3 (Model B) has on-board WiFi so you won't need the dongle.

What you want is very similar to a digital photo frame, so I would search for people who have already done that using google. I imagine that there would be plenty of free code/software out there on the internet.

All of this is a lot easier on the Raspberry Pi compared to using the Arduino.

---

[pcDuino](http://www.linksprite.com/linksprite-pcduino/) is another hardware platform much like the Raspberry Pi that would meet your requirements. The pcDuino is less popular than the Raspberry Pi and so there may be less open source code out there in cyberspace - but it would still be worth a try.